# Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

Tags: apex, trigger, error-messages, code

I am trying to add users to the chatter groups based on region field on User object using trigger and apex class.

When ever I am creating or updating a user it is giving **Invalid Cross reference key Error**

I hardcoded the Id's but still same error !!

**Class:**

```
@future
public static void groups(Set<Id> userIds)
{
    List<User> users=[select id,UserTheater__c,Name,Username from User where id in :userIds];
    List<String> groups=new List<String>{'A','B','C'};


    List<CollaborationGroup> chatGps=[select id, Name from CollaborationGroup where name in :groups];

    List<CollaborationGroupMember> chatGpMem=new List<CollaborationGroupMember>();
    for (User user : users)
    {
        for (CollaborationGroup chatterGroup : chatGps)
    {

    CollaborationGroupMember c =  new CollaborationGroupMember();
    if(user.reg__c == 'TL' && chatterGroup.name == 'A' ){   
        c.CollaborationGroupId=chatterGroup.id;
        c.MemberId = user.Id;
    }
    else if(user.reg__c == 'DL' && chatterGroup.name == 'B' ){
        c.CollaborationGroupId=chatterGroup.id;
        c.MemberId = user.Id;
    }

    else if(user.reg__c == 'ML' && chatterGroup.name == 'C' ){
        c.CollaborationGroupId=chatterGroup.id;
        c.MemberId = user.Id;
    }
    chatGpMem.add(c);

    insert chatGpMem;

}
```

**Trigger:**

```
trigger grpUser on User (after insert,after Update) 
{
  clsName.Groups(trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Comment: Can you debug your collection before your insert and ensure your id types match the expected type?

Comment: @Anusha Can you make your class without sharing ?

Comment: @JesseMilburn I debugged and I got the expected values

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I added without Sharing but still it is showing same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make this changes as follows:

Where matching group members to be added inside `if` block and `chatGpMem` list to be inserted outside `for` loop:

```
@future
public static void groups(Set<Id> userIds)
{
List<User> users=[select id,UserTheater__c,Name,Username from User where id in :userIds];
List<String> groups=new List<String>{'A','B','C'};

List<CollaborationGroup> chatGps=[select id, Name from CollaborationGroup where name in :groups];

List<CollaborationGroupMember> chatGpMem=new List<CollaborationGroupMember>();
for (User user : users)
{
    for (CollaborationGroup chatterGroup : chatGps)
    {
        CollaborationGroupMember c =  new CollaborationGroupMember();
        if(user.reg__c == 'TL' && chatterGroup.name == 'A' ){   
            c.CollaborationGroupId=chatterGroup.id;
            c.MemberId = user.Id;
            chatGpMem.add(c);
        }
        else if(user.reg__c == 'DL' && chatterGroup.name == 'B' ){
            c.CollaborationGroupId=chatterGroup.id;
            c.MemberId = user.Id;
            chatGpMem.add(c);
        }
        else if(user.reg__c == 'ML' && chatterGroup.name == 'C' ){
            c.CollaborationGroupId=chatterGroup.id;
            c.MemberId = user.Id;
            chatGpMem.add(c);
        }
}
if(chatGpMem.size()>0) insert chatGpMem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, It is working ! But it is invoking 2 times

Comment: you can use static variable to restrict second time call.